# Discord.py on_message: nothin happens when i type the message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'XXXXX'
prefix = "!"
client = discord.Client()

    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == prefix + "hey":
     await client.reply("hello there")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

in the first @client.event  when i use the command given there prefix + "hey", nothing happens. it doesnt give the desired reply

AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'reply'

thats the error i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `message.reply` instead of `client.reply`.

Note that is better to create commands using special discord.py decorator:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.command()
async def hey(ctx):
    ctx.reply("Hello there!")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score -1):

use `@client.listen()`, I encountered that before and `listen()` worked

Comment: `client.event` also works.

Comment: not for me, I did event() and it didn't respond to any other commands.

Comment: @Dekriel that’s because you did event() instead of event. You added ()

Comment: @thatrandomperson I didn't